# Angular Bootstrap Carousel - Fit images to square box without stretching

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have an angular carousel with several images, all of which are not the same size nor have the same aspect ratio, how can I get the images to fill a black square box say 250x250 pixels without stretching them? ie landscaped images will have black bars on top and bottom and portraits will have black bars left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `max-width` and `max-height` like this:

```css
figure {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/150">
</figure>
```